# modelling and simulation of a motor generator set for the replacement of diesel engines

Tags: generator, induction-motor, synchronous-motor

Can a motor-generator set with specifications and outputs as shown in the picture below be used to power a 16 kW, 220V house?

[image: results obtained from the simulation in MATLAB Simulink Software]

[image: input to the simulation]

Comment: As a minimum you need to convert the 400V MG output to 220V. Also what frequency is the MG and how does it compare to your house requirement?

Comment: The answer is yes.  Get a 240V generator.  But grass-hopper, what the true question is what powers the motor?